# Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag when adding new message type

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

i have added a new message type like it is described in the guide here.
http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages.html
but i am getting an error when i send it to my acceptor

this is the error i get from the acceptor:

`Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag`

i have tried changing the enum of the msgType to make it more unique.
also,
changing the configuration to use a different version of the FIX protocol

`BeginString=FIXT.1.1`

to `FIX.4.4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after searching ALOT, i have found a solution.

make sure that you did the following:

1. add the new message type to your custom data dictionary
2. used the data dictionary in the configuration
   `AppDataDictionary=./glossary/FIX50SP2_CUSTOM.xml`
3. updated the `transportDataDictionary` - add your custom message to it